# Kattis problem Dominos, run time error on the final testcase, am i missing something obvious or an edge case?

Tags: python, graph, runtime-error, depth-first-search, kosaraju-algorithm

I have spent a lot of time on the problem Dominos from kattis, see here: https://open.kattis.com/problems/dominos.

I am passing 3 testcases and on the final one I receive a runtime error. I suspect some out of bond errors might occur, but I really can't narrow down to the potential cause of the runtime error. I have pasted my code below and have tried to describe the different steps and the thinking process.
I am using Kosaraju's algorithm to identify the strongly connected components, through a DFS followed by a DFS on the reversed edges (Starting from the last node finished from the prior DFS).
Afterwards, I condense the graph to now only contain representatives of the SCCs, in order to obtain a directed acyclic graph. From here I count the indegree 0 of the SCC representatives as this will be the amount of bricks necessary to knock over manually by hand.
I hope this question is specific enough and some of you might have an idea what could be causing trouble.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def dfs(brick): # First traversal of graph primarily to generate the DSForder stack for 2nd traversal
    visited.add(brick)
    for neighbour in adj[brick]:
        if neighbour not in visited:
            dfs(neighbour)
    DFSorder.append(brick)

def dfs2(brick):
        visited.add(brick)
        SCCs[SCC_number].append(brick) # Append brick to the Strongly connected component list of bricks
        idx[brick] = SCCs[SCC_number][0] # Set representative as first element in the SCC
        for neighbour in adj_rev[brick]:
            if neighbour not in visited:
                dfs2(neighbour)

t = int(input()) # testcases

for _ in range(t):

    # Long list of needed things
    DFSorder = []
    SCC_number = 0
    SCCs = defaultdict(list)
    IndegreeSCC = defaultdict(int)
    idx=defaultdict(int)
    n,m = list(map(int,input().split()))
    visited = set()
    adj = defaultdict(set)
    adj_rev = defaultdict(set)
    adj_SCC = defaultdict(list)
    
    for _ in range(m):
        brick1,brick2 = list(map(int,input().split()))
        adj[brick1].add(brick2)
        adj_rev[brick2].add(brick1) # Reverse adjacency list for second DFS traversal

    for i in range(1,n+1): # First traversal to generate DFS order
        if i not in visited:
            dfs(i)
    
    visited = set() # Restart visited for 2nd reverse traversal

    for brick in DFSorder[::-1]: # Reverse traversal to determine SCCs
        if brick not in visited:
            dfs2(brick)
            SCC_number += 1
    
    for val in set(idx.values()): # Initially set all indegrees of SCC representatives to 0
        IndegreeSCC[val] = 0

    for key in adj: # Condense graph to SCCs (Only the representatives for each SCC is needed)
        for neighbour in adj[key]:
            if neighbour != idx[key] and idx[key] != idx[neighbour]:
                adj_SCC[idx[key]].append(idx[neighbour])
                IndegreeSCC[idx[neighbour]] += 1
    
    # Bricks that needs to be turned over manually can be found from the indegree 0 Strongly connected components
    print(sum([1 for val in list(IndegreeSCC.values()) if val == 0]))
```

Comment: What is the error?  Run it under a debugger to find error description and location.  You should tag your question with the language.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have now added python to the tags. How can i run it under a debugger when i dont know the testcase? It is submitted to kattis website and i only get information that it is "Runtime error". 
The previous tests was accepted and in each test there is several testcases included. This is why i find it odd that it does fail in the last testcase with a Runtime Error, that is not occuring in prior tests.

Comment: If you do not know the input that generates the error, then you are stuck.  My advice is to forget about the kattis website - it seems to be useless - and develop your own application with your own test cases.  This is how coding is done in the real world with real problems.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for alternative competitive programming websites? Or would you suggest something different for developing my problem solving skills in programming?

Comment: "would you suggest something different for developing my problem solving skills "  Yes.  Develop your own application with your own test cases.  Yse debugger to debug.  You will learn real coding skills,